# What plugin allows me to see which .dat files a webpage is accessing?

Tags: web-development

I recall using a chrome or firefox extension that pulled up a little bar at the bottom of my browser that showed the adress of the .dat file whenever a webpage I was on accessed it. Does anyone know the name of this, or a similar, plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for FireFox will show you all the URLs that a page has accessed.  You can put in a filter in the options to only show the `.dat` files.

Chrome has similar functionality built in.  There is a [network tab on the developer console](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/) that shows all the resources that a page uses.  There is no filter for it to show only `.dat` files.